# SKPhysicsJointLimit has a elastic behaviour, but i need a strong rope simulation

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody, skphysicsjoint

i am making a experimental visual project with SpriteKit.

I connected spritenodes (letter textures) with SKPhysicsJointLimit objects.
I also set the maximumLenght of the joints to 35, but it is not working properly: the more force drags at the joint, the longer it gets (more than 35).
Is there a possibility to set the strenght of the joints? So they are less elastic.

As you can see in this test picture the upper N and Z have very long joints
[image: As you can see in this test the upper N and Z have very long joints]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was really simple: The maximum length of the joints is set to a very small value. Therefore all conditions can not be met and the spritekit system has to exceed the maximum length.